# Animation eyelash cannot be shown in rendering

Tags: rendering

I making my hair mesh from Xgen (MAYA) imported it to Blender for animation.

I find out the hair would not be shown in rendering cause no face, but I have to use the modifier (*Surface Deform*) for animation.

[image]

[image]